# is this the correct use of aggregation

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, object-oriented-analysis

I want to simulate a cash register system. At the end of the transaction, the receipt would be displayed on the monitor. I've created a class called Receipt, it contains info about items purchased by the customer, subtotal, and customer's name. So, in the Receipt class, I created an ArrayList of product and a buyer object as instance variables. The toString() function would return a nice formatted string.

I am not sure if I should use ArrayList as an instance variable and I don't know if aggregation is the best choice here.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Receipt {
    private ArrayList<Product> purchased_products;
    private double total_price;
    private double total_with_tax;
    private Buyer buyer;

    public Receipt(Buyer buyer, ArrayList<Product> purchased_products, 
            double total_price, double total_with_tax) {
        this.purchased_products = new ArrayList<>(purchased_products);
        this.total_price = total_price;
        this.buyer = buyer;
        this.total_with_tax = total_with_tax;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String content = "Receipt: \nConvenience Store\n";
        content += "Balance Summary:\n";
        for (Product product : purchased_products) {
            content += product + "\n";
        }
        content += String.format("%d Subtotals: $%.2f\nAmount Paid: $%.2f\n", purchased_products.size(), total_price,
                total_with_tax);
        content += buyer.toString() + "\n";
        content += "Thank you for shopping with us. Have a wonderful day!\n";
        return content;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you want to try Decorator pattern for this purposes?

Comment: In Java camelCase is the convention for names, not underscores

Comment: I am not sure why you are worried about *aggregation* here

Comment: Using string concatenation inside loop is a bad idea. Use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine and you are doing it correct almost.

A small correction in constrctor is you need not to have a new array list again.

Just

```
 this.purchased_products = purchased_products;
```

Is enough.

Comment: but this would create a shallow copy of the array and I am not sure if I want that.

Comment: @GuanSummyHuang If this is the whole code of that class, you don't nee d that here.

Comment: I get it because this class doesn't mutate the array it simply displays it